# Adding key to values in json using Python

Tags: python, json

This is the structure of my JSON:

```
"docs": [
        {
            "key": [
                null,
                null,
                "some_name",
                "12345567",
                "test_name"
            ],
            "value": {
                "lat": "29.538208354844658",
                "long": "71.98762580927113"
            }
        },
```

I want to add the keys to the `key` list. This is what I want the output to look like:

```
"docs": [
            {
                "key": [
                    "key1":null,
                    "key2":null,
                    "key3":"some_name",
                    "key4":"12345567",
                    "key5":"test_name"
                ],
                "value": {
                    "lat": "29.538208354844658",
                    "long": "71.98762580927113"
                }
            },
```

What's a good way to do it. I tried this but doesn't work:

```
for item in data['docs']:
    item['test'] = data['docs'][3]['key'][0]
```

UPDATE 1

Based on the answer below, I have tweaked the code to this:

```
for number, item in enumerate(data['docs']):
    # pprint (item)
    # print item['key'][4]
    newdict["key1"] = item['key'][0]
    newdict["yek1"] = item['key'][1]
    newdict["key2"] = item['key'][2]
    newdict["yek2"] = item['key'][3]
    newdict["key3"] = item['key'][4]
    newdict["latitude"] = item['value']['lat']
    newdict["longitude"] = item['value']['long']
```

This creates the JSON I am looking for (and I can eliminate the list I had previously). How does one make this JSON persist outside the for loop? Outside the loop, only the last value from the dictionary is added otherwise.

Comment: As it stands, I don't believe your desired output is valid json

Comment: Make sure item is initialized as `{ }` and not `[ ]` (curly braces and not hard brackets

Answer (score 1):

In your first block, key is a list, but in your second block it's a dict. You need to completely replace the key item.

```
newdict = {}
for number,item in enumerate(data['docs']['key']):
    newdict['key%d' % (number+1)] = item
data['docs']['key'] = newdict
```

Comment: This doesn't work syntactically, `%` formatting takes precedence over addition so you need to use parentheses: `'key%d' % (number+1)`. Or use the new way: `'key{}'.format(number+1)`.

Comment: Doesn't work. I get this error: list indices must be integers, not str in the for statement. 'docs' is a list. To get to a key, we need something like this: data['docs'][3]['key']

Comment: You have the order wrong.  It should be `data['docs']['key'][3]`.

Comment: To drill inside the key, we do need the [3] after ['key']